# How to check the strings contains same characters in scala?

Tags: string, scala

I want to check the strings contains same characters. for example
My strings are :

```
BCE
CE
```

I want the result as,

```
BEC = BCE //true
ECB = BCE //true
CEB = BCE //true
CBE = BCE //true
EBC = BCE //true

CE = EC //true
```

Comment: @Kocko I use equals, substring , compareTo...BUt it doesn't work

Comment: What should the result be for `("A", "AA")`?

Comment: I suppose `false` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings can be implicitly converted to collections, and collections have a `toSet` method that make the contents a set, and set identity is independent of order.

Comment: OP didn't answer the comment question whether duplicates are counted. Compare `s groupBy identity`. Or for fun, `s.permutations contains s2`.

Comment: @som-snytt - If we're having fun, how about `(s diff s2) + (s2 diff s) == ""`?

Answer (score 4):

Consider this approach,

```
implicit class RichString(val s1: String) extends AnyVal {
  def sameAs(s2: String) = s1.sorted == s2.sorted
}
```

Use it like this, `"CBE".sameAs("BCE")` .

Answer (score 1):

It seems, from your examples, that you only want to check if the string is a permutation of another string. A quick way of doing it is to just sort the chars and compare the result. A more efficient method is to build a histogram of one of the strings and then go through the other string and decrement the histogram count for each char as you find them in the second string. If at the end you have an empty histogram the strings are the same.